# localhost.server appearing in my header when users receive emails. How do i remove this?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, localhost

I am using CakePHP

```
} 
public function send_email($to,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f registration@ccfordmedia.com")
{
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->from(array('registration@ccfordmedia.com' => 'Registration')); 
    $email->to($to);
    $email->subject($subject);                
    $email->emailFormat('html');
    $email->send($body);        
}
```

Any one can help me

Comment: Where exactly in your header? Can you post the relevant header, as well? Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function send_email($to,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f registration@ccfordmedia.com")
{
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('registration@ccfordmedia.com' => 'Registration')); 
$email->to($to);
$email->replyTo("registration@ccfordmedia.com");
$email->subject($subject);                
$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->send($body);        
}
```